# how to include vendor and other ignored directories/files in jenkins builds using GIT

Tags: php, git, jenkins

i have a git repository where i have the following directory structure:

- src/
- vendor/
- app/
- public/

vendor/ contains as you'd expect, 3rd party libraries (symfony, etc) which i do not want included as part of the repository. as a result of this, in my jenkins template which i have set up as 'Poll SCM' so builds can be automated from commits, it does not copy over the vendor/ directory into the workspace build, and so test fail because the library is not included in part of the build.

i came across git submodules whilst doing some troubleshooting into this, but im not sure they are the answer. as i'm sure im not the only one to use jenkins with the git plugin to create builds, and with ignored files/directories how can i go about getting the vendor/ directory and files across without putting them into the git repository?

Comment: What are you using for your build? Maven?

Comment: Ant, although i'm sure the issue is with getting git to somehow include the ignored directories when building.

Answer (score 0):

managed to find a workaround after digging in the Jenkins Job Configure screen - under the 'Build' section, aswell as 'Invoke Ant' there was an option to 'execute shell' ... i put the line 'composer install' in there and that successfully installs everything needed from the vendor/ folder before running ant and then the unit tests.